# Grabbing image from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, wordpress-plugin-creation

How do I grab an image from an amazon with a format like this:

https://platform.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/listing/31767-84007-dwBVIaLkhsGzpK4sfxaS-T07Gd-EXAd78l8lsJpeuYM-618cf68ce2350

I got this data from a Booking Engine API, and there's no other way to get a different result.

I am using WordPress and "media_sideload_image" doesn't accept it as a valid URL.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to Wordpress, [tag:wordpress-plugin-creation], or [tag:amazon-s3]?

Comment: It literally isn't a valid URL. There's nothing you can do unless the place where you got it will give you the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Same Issues was for me, I made the file public I was able to access my image as https://metapyxl.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1696425186798_1.png

So you need to make your image public on S3 bucket.

I attached images to update permission on S3 bucket.

[Allow public access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEk7X.png)

[Allow Bucket policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYb9c.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';

function upload_image_from_url($image_url) {
    // Check if the URL is valid
    if (filter_var($image_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        // Get the file type
        $file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($image_url), null);

        // Prepare an array of data for the attachment
        $attachment = array(
            'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name(basename($image_url)),
            'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
        );

        // Try to upload the image
        $attachment_id = media_sideload_image($image_url, 0, null, 'id');

        if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
            // The image was successfully uploaded, and $attachment_id contains the attachment ID.
            return $attachment_id;
        } else {
            // An error occurred during the upload.
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Example usage:
$image_url = 'https://metapyxl.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1696425186798_1.png';
$attachment_id = upload_image_from_url($image_url);

if ($attachment_id) {
    // The image was uploaded successfully. You can use $attachment_id as needed.
} else {
    // There was an error uploading the image.
}
```